# Bootstrap: add add-on below input

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I add span below input using bootsrap css?
I need to do something like this: [image]

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/205/

you can do it with pure css like is shown below:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <input type="text" class="form-control has-add-on"/>
    <div class="btm-add-on">
        <strong>Some Text</strong> <input type="checkbox"/>
    </div>
</div>

.btm-add-on {
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    border-top: none;
}
.has-add-on {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}
```